# how to add dyanmic parent child relationship in jira custom field?

Tags: migration, jira, bugzilla

I am trying to migrate some of my bugzilla data to JEERA. I have some custom fields in bugzilla which has dynamic parent-child relationship. for exa-
Suppose I have Labels `"India" "China" "Russia"`,
when I click on Label lets say `"India"`,   then it should fetch and show only cities from India and **not all cities**.
Right now , I am able to create `Labels` and `cities` custome fields in jeera but lacking dynamic nature.
I will be thankful, if anyone has any idea over this.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *Select List (cascading)* custom field type would best solution here.

As a bit workaround for relate two custom fields between each other you can use [ScriptRunner Behaviours](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/behaviours-overview.html). It's like a Groovy definition for frontend logic. Conceptually:

- City field must contains all Cities for all Countries.
- Create a Behaviour for a Country field. It means when user will change/select a Country field a Behaviour will be run.
- In behaviour write code that will get currently selected country and then fulfil a Cities field based on selected country.

Useful methods: getFieldById(fieldId), formField.getValue(), formField.setFieldOptions(Iterable). [API Documentation](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/behaviours-api-quickref.html).

Comment: @sintasy..thanks for your quick response. I have given a try to cascading already. Cascading will give parent child relationship in one field. However, I want it to be across the fields.

Comment: Unfortunately there no features about create relationships between two fields in Jira Core or Software. Jira custom fields usually independed. Maybe some plugin be capable to do this. However I never notice such a features in any of plugins (but there a lot of them in marketplace). Also there is one way but it's require you to a bit sink to ScriptRunner.

Answer (score 0):

I think @sintasy is right.

If you want N-countries have their own cities, cascading select list just fit your requrement.

If you want N-countries * M-other-things, which have no relation with countries, two select lists will fit your requrement.

If you want more complex feature, then I don't known.